Is there a chess computer that prioritizes winning material after ensuring king safety?
I'm curious if there exists a chess computer or engine that specifically prioritizes winning material, but only after ensuring the safety of the king. Most engines seem to balance various factors like position, material, and king safety. However, I'm looking for one that has a clear hierarchy: first ensuring the king's safety and then focusing on capturing material. Does such an engine exist, and if so, what are some examples?

Is my king safe if my opponent has two extra pieces?

@Evargalo , I said that it prioritizes winning material over other advantages (excluding checkmate) but first ensures that my king isn't getting checkmated. If opponent has two extra pieces, it doesn't necessarily mean I'm losing, I might have sacrificed it for checkmating the opponent, I might also be losing but the engine should first try it's best to ensure king safety and then winning back material.
